# Pex run in loop after reporting?

Tags: performance, pex

i run pex by command line on a class of about 2200 methods.

After 2 days of elaboration, I think to have the test suite and report html, pex finished this morning at 8.05 AM and the list file modified is at 08.40 AM.

The last line of output are :

```
08:05:08.3> [finished] execution time 2.08:05:08.3014942.
        -- 0 critical errors, 0 errors, 0 warnings.
        -- 83635 generated tests, 1 failing, 83635 new, 0 inconclusive.

[coverage] generating coverage reports...
[reports] generating reports...
[reports] report path: reports\121005.001302.3848.pex
```

The process pex.exe is running continuos, But what is happened ? After about 3.5 hours ( now for me is 12.15 pm ) its maybe is going to loop or what is the operation is it doing ?

CPU is full and memory too ( process pex 1.5G of RAM)

Do you think I have to stop it?
Thanks best regards.

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days and about 14h I stop the process :

```
[coverage] generating coverage reports...
[reports] generating reports...
[reports] report path: reports\121005.001302.3848.pex
!error! [reports] rendering of coverage reports failed: exit code 1 - 0x1
Microsoft Pex v0.94.51023.0 -- http://research.microsoft.com/pex -- v4.0.30319
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation 2007-2010. All rights reserved.

[tests] could not resolve test framework, using default (Visual Studio Unit Test
)
[reports] html report: reports\121005.001302.3848.pex\report.html
        LAUNCHER FAILED
unexpected failure: exit code 1 - 0x1
```

Maybe I have few resource ( 2G RAM and a dual core ) and pex doesn't do the report.html